# Dark mode toggle

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to create a logic to toggle the button (images) back and forth and switch between styles (light/dark mode) infinitely, but I'm failing to do so. Can you give me some clue how this can be accomplished?

With this code I am succeeding to toggle styles only once...

```
let toggleDark =
    document.getElementById('btn-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'white';
    document.querySelector('.sun').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.querySelector('.moon').style.visibility = 'visible';

    toggleLight();
});

function toggleLight() {
    document.getElementById('btn-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'black';
    document.querySelector('.sun').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.querySelector('.moon').style.visibility = 'hidden';
})};
```

Here's the HTML part...

```
<body class="dark light">

<div>
    <button id="btn-toggle">
        <img src="weather-sunny.png" alt="Light Mode" id="light_mode" class="sun">
        <img src="weather-night.png" alt="Dark Mode" id="dark_mode" class="moon">
    </button>
</div>

<main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero quo, officiis repellat quam accusantium neque pariatur! Facilis nemo enim cumque atque, eaque perferendis corporis aliquid, temporibus, incidunt, sint sed sunt.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be an end tag, `</body>`?

Comment: I think html parsers are lenient enough to ignore that

Comment: Yes! I forgot to copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the same eventListener to the same element, both will execute after both are set. It won't toggle between, and you could do this in one function with a Boolean.

**Note**: Change the toggled to true if the beginning mode is white and false if it's black.

```
function colormode(toggle) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = (toggle) ?'black':'white';
    document.querySelector('body').style.color = (toggle) ? 'white':'black';
    document.querySelector('.sun').style.visibility = (toggle) ? 'hidden':'visible';
    document.querySelector('.moon').style.visibility = (toggle) ? 'visible':'hidden';
};

var toggled = false;
document.getElementById('btn-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
   colormode(toggled);
   toggled = !toggled;
});
```

Comment: Wow it's working! That easy!? I would have spent days figuring this out! Although I guess that the same effect can be accomplished with fewer lines of code. Well I hope i will get to that too some day. Thanks.

Comment: Youre welcome, I can update my answer with a shorter version if you wish

Comment: Why not, I am curious to see it.

Comment: Have shortened it a decent bit, just merged the two functions with ternary operators

Comment: Whats happening? Any errors? What is happening compared to the previous version

Comment: My bad, have noticed the error. When calling the function `colormode()` I put the parameter as `toggle` when infact the variable is called `toggled`. I have updated it, this should work now

Comment: All good now and I definitely prefer this shorter version. Although I think that brackets around `toggle` in ternary operators are not necessary.

Comment: Good point, you can get rid of them if you want. I normally just put them there because of habit. Either one works